# Videos from HTTPS are not playing in android app

Tags: java, android

I am trying to play videos downloaded from server having https url , but it showed

"Sorry , this video cannot be played."

for few android devices. I have tried many things but nothing works. It is working for HTTP Urls. 
Also I found that videos for HTTPS can only played beyond Android OS 3.1:

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

**Can somebody suggest me the solution for this. Any help would really appreciated.**

Here is my code that I am using to play video :

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(videoURL);
    video.setVideoURI(uri);
    ctlr            = new MediaController(this);
    ctlr.setMediaPlayer(video);
    video.setMediaController(ctlr);
    video.requestFocus();
    video.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    video.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    video.setKeepScreenOn(true);
    video.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your activity

```
int SDK_INT = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

        if (SDK_INT > 8) {

            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                    .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        }
```

Comment: Nirav Ranpara ,I have tried this solution. I have put this code in onCreate method , but it does not solve the problem. I am still experiencing same alert meesage of  :

"Sorry , this video cannot be played."